# Rails 4 -Simple Form how to save key and display value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, key-value

I'm trying to make an app in Rails 4. I use simple form for forms.

I have an attribute called 'self_governance' in my model.

I've written a helper method so that I can define 5 levels which can be stored for this attribute, but which are displayed to the user as options (rather than numbers 1 .. 5).

In my helper, I have:

```
module PreferencesHelper

    def self_gov_selector
        [
            [ 'tier 1','1'],
            [ 'tier 2','2'],
            [ 'tier 3','3'],
            [ 'tier 4','4'],
            [ 'tier 5','5'],
        ]
    end
```

In my form, I then have:

```
<%= f.input :self_governance, :label => "Select your tier", collection: self_gov_selector %>
```

Then in my show, I'm trying to figure out how to display 'tier 1' instead of '1'.

I have tried:

```
<%= @preference.self_governance %>

<%= @preference.self_gov_selector %>
```

I can't find anything that works. They all display 1 instead of Tier 1 in the views.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `params` posted by the form will only include the second value in the array, so you're likely storing your value as an integer in your database table.

A simple solution is to use an `enum` to map the integers you're storing to the values they represent:

**In your Preference model:**

```
enum self_governance: {
                          tier_1: 1,
                          tier_2: 2,
                          tier_3: 3,
                          tier_4: 4,
                          tier_5: 5
                        }
```

**Then update your view accordingly:**

```
<%= @preference.self_governance.try(:humanize) %>
```

**EDIT:**

An additional bonus of this approach is that you can replace your helper method with calling the enum directly:

```
f.input :self_governance, as: :select, label: "your label", collection: Preference.self_governances.map { |key, val| [key.humanize, val] }
```

Comment: Actually - when I try this, I get this error: undefined method `self_governance' for #<Class:0x007fde5b9fb500>
Did you mean?  self_governances

Comment: Yes: `Preference.self_governances.map { |key, val| [key.humanize, val] }` should work. Sorry about the delayed response.