# Rails 4 - how to use enum?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

I'm trying to make an app on Rails 4.

I posted this question and got some advice: [Rails 4 -Simple Form how to save key and display value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36539924/rails-4-simple-form-how-to-save-key-and-display-value)

I am trying to figure out how to implement this advice.

At the moment, I have a preference model with:

```
enum self_governance: {
                          tier_1: 1,
                          tier_2: 2,
                          tier_3: 3,
                          tier_4: 4,
                          tier_5: 5
                        }

  enum autonomy: {
                          tier_11: 1,
                          tier_21: 2,
                          tier_31: 3,
                          tier_41: 4,
                          tier_51: 5
                        }
```

In my preference form, I have:

```
<%= f.input :self_governance, as: :select, label: "Select your governance approach", collection: Preference.self_governance.to_a.map { |p| [p.humanize, p] } %>
```

I have a preferences show view:

```
<%= @organisation.preference.self_governance.try(:humanize) %>
```

When I save all this and try it, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError at /preferences/1/edit
undefined method `self_governance' for #<Class:0x007fde5b9fb500>
Did you mean?  self_governances
```

Can anyone see how to make this work?

Do I maybe need to add def/end tags to the enum in the preference model? I don't have any experience with using the code 'enum'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're so close :)  The fix is right in the error.

Your select is calling

```
Preference.self_governance.to_a.map { |p| [p.humanize, p] }
```

And your error tells you the pluralization is wrong.  Remember that if you call enum on a single object, it will be

```
@preference.self_governance
```

But if you call on the model itself, Preference, and request a collection it's plural.

```
Preference.self_governances
```

Because `enum` is special, uour enum's could just be arrays, instead of  hashes:

```
enum self_governance: [ tier_1, tier_2, tier_3, tier_4, tier_55 ]

enum autonomy: [ tier_11, tier_21, tier_31, tier_41, tier_51 ]
```

Your view would look like:

```
<%= f.input :self_governance, as: :select, label: "Select your governance approach", collection: Preference.self_governances.map { |key, value| [key.humanize, key] } %>
```

It will store the index number of the array, like magic :)

Comment: Thanks! That worked, but now I get this error: undefined method `humanize' for ["tier_1", 1]:Array. When I delete 'humanise' from the select line, I then get a form which displays both the key and the value. I only want to show the value but store the key. Is 'enum' the wrong thing to be trying to use?

Comment: If you don't have a reason for using a hash, you can switch to an array, quite often  enum's are simple and just an array.  Since you are using a simple key (like the number 3) then you can just use the array index when you need it (for instance, that's what will be stored in the db)

Comment: How would I do that?, I'm just trying to get the view to display the text and the db to store the number

Answer (score 1):

Rails pluralizes the enum collection for you, so yours could be `self_governances`, for instance.

What that means is that `Preference.self_governances` would return the hash with the definitions and the attribute that actually holds the value is the one in singular like `@preference.self_governance`

An example:

```
@preference = Preference.new
@preference.self_governance = Preference.self_governances[:tier_1]
```

When you use `enum` what rails will do internally is add a pluralized class method definition with the name that you defined that will return a hash with the values and, will use the name that you defined, as it was written by you, for an attribute accessor that will either get/set the actual value of the enumeration on instances of your object.

Another, common use is for status, given a `Test` class:

```
enum status: {
  active: 1,
  inactive: 2
}
```

So for the above sample rails would add a `Test.statuses` methods that simply returns the values of your enum. Then, for an instance of a `Test` object you would have an accessor `@instance.status` with the name of your name which you can use to get or set a status from the hash returned by `Test.statuses`

Hopefully it makes sense.