# Rails 4 - key value pair

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

I'm trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I've recently asked these 2 questions, and taken the advice in the responses. [Rails 4 - how to use enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36560700/rails-4-how-to-use-enum)

I'm still struggling.

I have a form with an input selector:

```
<%= f.input :self_governance, as: :select, label: "Select your governance approach", collection: Preference.self_governances.to_a.map { |p| [p.to_s.humanize, p] } %>
```

When I save this and try it, the select menu shows:

["tier_1", 1]

What I want is to display: Tier 1

At the moment, I have a preference model with:

```
enum self_governance: {
                          tier_1: 1,
                          tier_2: 2,
                          tier_3: 3,
                          tier_4: 4,
                          tier_5: 5
                        }

  enum autonomy: {
                          tier_11: 1,
                          tier_21: 2,
                          tier_31: 3,
                          tier_41: 4,
                          tier_51: 5
                        }
```

I have a preferences show view:

```
<%= @organisation.preference.self_governance.try(:humanize) %>
```

Also, when I accept the form problem (for now) and try to render the show page, I get this error:

```
'["tier_1", 1]' is not a valid self_governance
```

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

I just want to save the number 1 in the database, but display the words 'Tier 1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your form to properly return a collection of keys and values from your enum. `Preference.self_governances` is a type of hash object.r Rather than call `to_a`, just iterate over the keys and values:

```
<%= f.input :self_governance, as: :select, label: "Select your governance approach", collection: Preference.self_governances.map { |key, val| [key.humanize, key] } } %>
```

If we look at just the output of:
`Preference.self_governances.map { |key, val| [key.humanize, key] }`

We get the following:

```
[
  ["Tier 1", "tier_1"], 
  ["Tier 2", "tier_2"]
  ...
]
```

Note that the first value is what gets shown as the `select` label and the second value is what gets sent to your controller within the `param`.

**EDIT:**

When using an enum, you can assign either the key or value of the enum to the field.

```
preference.self_governance = 1 # Works
preference.self_governance = :tier_1  # Works
preference.self_governance = "tier_1" # Works
```

But you can't assign the value as a string:

```
preference.self_governance = '1'
=> "ArgumentError: '1' is not a valid self_governance"  # Doesn't work, tries to look for key '1' in enum, but doesn't exist.
```

So make sure you pass the key of the selected enum (i.e. "tier_1") aback to your form or else you ma

Comment: thanks Anthony. That worked in the form, but when I press submit, I get an error that says: '1' is not a valid self_governance

Comment: Ah, right. Convert your value to an integer, so it matches the type of your column: `val.to_i`.

Comment: Thanks trying it now

Comment: that doesn't work, it still produces the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Ah yes, your form might be casting the value to a string when sending to the controller use: `<%= f.input :self_governance, as: :select, label: "Select your governance approach", collection: Preference.self_governances.map { |key, val| [key.humanize, key] } } %>`

Comment: See my edit, I've updated the answer, explaining the error.

Comment: Thank you! That's really very much appreciated.